# Forced Print Server Defaults Without Restriction

Tags: windows-server-2008, printing

Here's our scenario.

Windows 2k8 print server hosting a large Ricoh multi-function color laser printer for everyone in the office to use. Printers are NOT deployed with Group Policy.

Management wants the printer to default on printing black and white, but still allow people to print in color if they need to.

Setting the default in the driver will work for a freshly added printer, but as soon as someone changes the setting to print in color on their client, it stays that way until they manually change it back. Ideally, we would like it to forget whatever settings the user applied when they close whatever application they're printing from, but at the very least, I'd like it to reset these settings on login.

Is there a 'right' or 'easy' way to accomplish this? The only thing I can think of that I know will work, is pushing a login script that deletes and re-adds the printer... but this seems... hacky. My google-fu on this topic is evidently not very strong.

I appreciate whatever help you can give me, thanks!

Comment: Why don´t you ask Ricoh support ? I haven´t worked with Ricoh yet, how I would do it on a Konica Minolta : create two EKC accounts (cost accounts), one b&w only, one with color/b&w rights, setup the b&w only as default and let the users use the second account when they want to print color.